# Linq on Table View

Tags: .net, linq, view

I have following type

```
public class TransactionDetails
{ 
    public int TransID {get; set;}
    public List<string> OrderID { get; set; }
}
```

What should be the Linq query on the following table View (say Trans_View) to fill this `TransactionDetails` custom type with following data from view.

View record in following row format:

```
         TransID     OrderID      
            1           ABC
            1           DEF
            1           IJK
            2           XYZ
            2           PQR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var transactionDetails = Trans_View.GroupBy(x => x.TransID, x => x.OrderID)
    .Select(g => new TransactionDetails() 
        {
            TransID = g.Key, 
            OrderID = g.ToList() 
        });
```

Comment: Hi 2Kay,I tried the above solution, but it is not working,Generated following result

Comment: Hi 2Kay,I tried the above solution, but it is not working,Generated following result

Comment: Error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

Comment: Hi 2Kay,I tried the above solution, but it is not working,Generated following result TransID OrderID
1         colection {ABC,ABC,ABCHi 2Kay,I tried the above solution, but it is not working,
Generated following result 
TransID OrderID
1         colection {ABC,ABC,ABC}
2.        colection {XYZ,XYZ}}
2.        colection {XYZ,XYZ}

Comment: @Prasad Kanaparthi, `Trans_View` contsins `string` as orderId, not list of `string`. so `g.ToList()` returns `List<string>`. what is the problem?

Comment: `g.ToList()` return `List<List<string>>` Not `List<string>`. I posted the error please see.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var transactionDetails = Trans_View.GroupBy(x => x.TransID)
    .Select(t => new TransactionDetails()
        {
            TransID = t.Key,
            OrderID = t.Select(o => o.OrderID).FirstOrDefault(),
        });
```